# sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer - не могу заполнить признак модальностью

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

У меня есть категориальные признаки. В них есть пропуски. Я хочу пропуски заполнить значением моды.
Для этого я использую модуль библиотеки `from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer` и делаю следующие:
`imr = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'most_frequent', axis = 0)`
`imr = imr.fit(df['Var223'])`
`imputer_data = imr.transform(df['Var223'].values)`
Далее я получаю ошибку: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'LM8l689qOp'`  причём значение `LM8l689qOp` является модой признака `Var223`  но далее я не понимаю что делать. Исходя из ошибки он не может конвертировать строку в число с плавающей точкой (но мне и не нужно чтобы это стало числом).Ссылка на датафрейм: 
https://yadi.sk/i/9iG_W6vOx5PseQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer` вы должны были получить следующее предупреждение:

> ```
> DeprecationWarning: Class Imputer is deprecated; Imputer was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22.
> ```

```
  Import impute.SimpleImputer from sklearn instead.
```

> ```
>   warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
> ```

Пример использования `impute.SimpleImputer`:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 

imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
df["Var223"] = imp.fit_transform(df[["Var223"]])[:, 0]
```

---

Результат:

```
In [15]: df["Var223"].value_counts()
Out[15]:
LM8l689qOp    33475
jySVZNlOJy     4780
M_8D           1619
bCPvVye         126
Name: Var223, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы как всегда помогли!